# Associate context information with Tap Gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UITableView that has two images per row. These images come from a data structure. I would like to set up a tap event and have the tap event handler retrieve the data structure based on the selected image. Is there a way to associate context data?

Or do I have to maintain a mapping that maps uiimage to my data?

I also don't want to have a separate handler per image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a tap gesture, you could implement something like:

```
- (void)didRecognizeTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:self.tableView];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];

        if (indexPath != nil)
        {
            MyCustomCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            point = [self.tableView convertPoint:point toView:cell];

            if (CGRectContainsPoint(cell.imageView1.frame, point))
            {
                //it touches image 1
            }
            else if (CGRectContainsPoint(cell.imageView2.frame, point))
            {
              //it touches images 2
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: yes, sorry.. You are right `point = [self.tableView convertPoint:point toView:cell];`

Comment: Thank you - the indexPathForRowAtPoint was helpful. This is because during the tap event, the table cell did not have an updated selected row. This in combination with setting a tag on the imageView allowed me to uniquely identify the image.

Answer (score 0):

You could give your image views tags based on the indexPath.row, and then you can get that tag, which will give you the index into your data structure. You can get the tag from your gesture recognizer's view property which will point to the image view that was tapped.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't end up using the tag to as a unique index, but the tag was unique per row. Combining that with the above method to get the selected row was what I needed.